# How to add label over mean of points in scatterplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot on which I need to add labels over the mean of points.

data is a numpy array of shape (1000,2)

```
scatter=plt.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1], c = labels, label = set(labels))
plt.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(),
                 title="Classes",loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

The scatter plot has 10 labels of different colours.

The ideal output would be for 9 to be printed somewhere around the center/mean of the yellow points.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1beHFiN link to scatter plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib`s [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) or [`annotation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).

For calculating the coordinates, you just need the mean of the two data coordinates where `labels` is 9:

```
# labels = np.array(labels)  # just if labels is not a np.array yet

lblxy = np.mean(data[labels==9], 0)

plt.text(*lblxy, '9', ha='center', va='center')
```